# My external hard drive just beeped, what does it mean?

Tags: mac, external-hard-drive

I have an external hard drive (a "Seagate Expansion Portable 2 TB" model) connected to a Mac. While copying some files, the hard drive just emitted a clear high pitched beep (I'm pretty much certain it was a beep and not mechanical noise).

What does the beep mean?

Comment: It most certainly was a mechanical noise. There’s no other way for a hard drive to generate sound.

Comment: It might also be noteworthy that one of my ST4000VX has been making noises from the start. It’s still working 27.000 hours later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beeping noise you hear comes from the struggles of the drive’s mechanical components. When the delicate instruments within your hard disk drive start to fail.

Inside your hard drive, a spindle motor hub spins the hard disk platters inside at several thousand revolutions per minute. To read and write data to these disks, delicate read/write heads hover just a few nanometers away from the platter surfaces. **If the heads crash onto the platters, they can get stuck and clamp down on the platters, holding them in place.** The beeping sound actually comes from the spindle motor hub as it tries in vain to spin the platters.

You should create a backup of your files while your drive is still working.

Comment: You should mark your sources when you copy text from [another website](https://www.gillware.com/data-recovery-services/hard-drive-repair/seagate-drive-repair-hard-drive-beeping/). Otherwise it could be considered plagiarism.

Comment: Would this not be a constant thing? I remember it doing this about three times, weeks apart. Sounding exactly the same each time. I do have backups of everything in the cloud so I'm not worried about it failing.